# regarding for similar of two sets whether all function define from set A to setB be bijective or not

Tags: real-analysis

We say set of integer and natural no are similar so there should be bijection between them but my doubt is that if we define a function y=x^3 then for y=-8 we cannot find pre image which is natural no. So I want to ask whether there should exist only one function that is bijective or every function should be bijective

Comment: There are infinitely many bijections between the integers and the naturals. There are also infinitely many functions from the naturals to the integers that are not bijections. Similar observations hold for finite sets of the same cardianlity.

Comment: Have we answered your question?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

Similar means that there is at least one function which is a bijection between them ; you noticed already that it  can't mean all functions . The function f determined by  f(2n) =n for n=0,1,2,3,... and f(2n-1)=-n for n=1,2,3,4,,,, is a bijection of the natural numbers 0,1,2,3,4,...(I include 0 as a natural number) with the set of all of the integers (positive,negative and zero).